# Adding all months in past year in mysql query result, even if no rows

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am looking for a way to retrieve all subscriptions to vacancies over the past 12 months. Since not every vacancy will have a subscription in each month, some rows will have to return 0, but right now it's just not in the result set. How do I add the missing rows?

The tables I use are the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar_months` (
  `month_id` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `en_abbr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `en_long` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nl_abbr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nl_long` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `calendar_months` (`month_id`, `en_abbr`, `en_long`, `nl_abbr`, `nl_long`) VALUES
(1, 'jan', 'January', 'jan', 'Januari'),
(2, 'feb', 'February', 'feb', 'Februari'),
(3, 'mar', 'March', 'mrt', 'Maart'),
(4, 'apr', 'April', 'apr', 'April'),
(5, 'may', 'May', 'mei', 'Mei'),
(6, 'jun', 'June', 'jun', 'Juni'),
(7, 'jul', 'July', 'jul', 'Juli'),
(8, 'aug', 'August', 'aug', 'Augustus'),
(9, 'sep', 'September', 'sep', 'September'),
(10, 'oct', 'October', 'okt', 'Oktober'),
(11, 'nov', 'November', 'nov', 'November'),
(12, 'dec', 'December', 'dec', 'December');

CREATE TABLE `vacancies` (
  `vacancy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'title',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
) ;

CREATE TABLE `vacancy_subscriptions` (
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vacancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscription_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message` text
)
```

I use the following query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(cm.nl_long, ' ', YEAR(v.create_time)) as label, YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear, MONTH(v.create_time) as vacmonth, COUNT(*) as totalsubscriptions
FROM `calendar_months` as cm
LEFT JOIN `vacancies` as v on cm.month_id = month(v.create_time)
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_subscriptions` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE
  (v.create_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH)))
  AND v.is_deleted = 0
  AND v.org_id = 1
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC
```

And this gives me the result I am looking for.

```
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------------+
|     label     | vacyear | vacmonth | totalsubscriptions |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| Oktober 2017  |    2017 |       10 |                  5 |
| November 2017 |    2017 |       11 |                  1 |
| December 2017 |    2017 |       12 |                 13 |
| Maart 2018    |    2018 |        3 |                  4 |
| April 2018    |    2018 |        4 |                  5 |
+---------------+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

But how do I add the months with no subscriptions in the past 12 months with the last column just being "0"? Like this:

```
+----------------+---------+----------+--------------------+
|     label      | vacyear | vacmonth | totalsubscriptions |
+----------------+---------+----------+--------------------+
| Mei 2017       |    2017 |        5 |                  0 |
| Juni 2017      |    2017 |        6 |                  0 |
| Juli 2017      |    2017 |        7 |                  0 |
| Augustus 2017  |    2017 |        8 |                  0 |
| September 2017 |    2017 |        9 |                  0 |
| Oktober 2017   |    2017 |       10 |                  5 |
| November 2017  |    2017 |       11 |                  1 |
| December 2017  |    2017 |       12 |                 13 |
| Januari 2018   |    2018 |        1 |                  0 |
| Februari 2018  |    2018 |        2 |                  0 |
| Maart 2018     |    2018 |        3 |                  4 |
| April 2018     |    2018 |        4 |                  5 |
+----------------+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

UPDATE: I have created an SQL fiddle containing some data! http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75db76

Comment: put your where clause in the on clause- the where clause is limiting the result set right now

Comment: @DanielMarcus Thanks for your answer! Even though a step in the right direction, this does not resolve the issue unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Move your where condition related  to left join table in the on clause

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(cm.nl_long, ' ', YEAR(v.create_time)) as label, YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear, ifnull(MONTH(v.create_time),0) as vacmonth, ifnull(COUNT(*),0) as totalsubscriptions
FROM `calendar_months` as cm
LEFT JOIN `vacancies` as v on cm.month_id = month(v.create_time) 
    AND  (v.create_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH)))
    AND v.is_deleted = 0
    AND v.org_id = 1
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_subscriptions` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth, label
ORDER BY vacyear ASC, vacmonth ASC
```

otherwise the where condition work as an inner join and don't return rows if the value don't match

do the fact  you have not the year for all the month you could use  a cross join on union for get this value

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(cm.nl_long, ' ', y.my_year) as label, YEAR(v.create_time) as vacyear
    ,  ifnull(MONTH(v.create_time), 0) as vacmonth, ifnull(COUNT(*),0) as totalsubscriptions
FROM `calendar_months` as cm
CROSS JOIN (
    select 2018 my_year
    from dual 
    union 
    select 2017 
    from dual 
) y 
LEFT JOIN `vacancies` as v on cm.month_id = month(v.create_time) 
    AND  (v.create_time >= (DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH)))
    AND v.is_deleted = 0
    AND v.org_id = 1
LEFT JOIN `vacancy_subscriptions` as vs on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
GROUP BY vacyear, vacmonth, label
ORDER BY y.my_year ASC, vacmonth ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By using your SQL it did not result in what i expected, but in this: https://imgur.com/UXY2TuA

Comment: strange  ..  having the sample you have provided  you should select  a rows for each month  ..

Comment: anyway answer  updated  adding label to group by condition too

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer! However, by grouping on label, the result stays the same as in the screenshot...

Comment: I have add a suggestion hope is useful

Comment: Hello scaisEdge, thank you for your help! I tried your second suggestion, the result is not what I expect, it is this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75db76/2

Comment: obviusly there also rows  for month year that become for cross join between month and year  .. (you could use where for filter the rows  that you don't need)  .. anyway asnwer  updated  with a better order by

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is broken.  Your calendar table needs to include both the month and the year -- and the first date of the month (for convenience).

Then you can do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(cm.nl_long, ' ', cm.year) as label, COUNT(*) as totalsubscriptions
FROM calendar_months cm LEFT JOIN
     vacancies v 
     ON cm.month_id = month(v.create_time) AND
        cm.year = year(v.create_time) AND
        v.is_deleted = 0 AND
        v.org_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     `vacancy_subscriptions` vs
     on v.vacancy_id = vs.vacancy_id 
WHERE cm.month_start_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH))
GROUP BY label
ORDER BY MIN(cm.month_start_date);
```

Notes:

- The filtering on all but the first table should be in the `ON` clauses (for `LEFT JOIN`.
- The `GROUP BY` needs to be on fields in the first table.
- If you have a real calendar table (rather than just a list of months), then you can filter for the past year on that table.
- You probably don't want to filter on `NOW()` -- you'll get 13 months of data, with partial first and last months.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the calendar table.. Is this a table that contains every year/month/day for the next 100 years orso?

Comment: @Dennis . . . That would be a useful calendar table.